# ¿Copiar directorio con PHP conservando propiedades (fecha creación / modificación)?

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con las propiedades de un fichero que indican su antigüedad y requiero hacer copias de directorios completos. Las copias tienen la fecha del momento de la copia como momento de creación.
¿Hay una forma de copiar directorios o ficheros y mantener las propiedades originales?

Answer (score 2):

Es muy abierta la pregunta, pero como no estas pidiendo ninguna tarea/ayuda de alguna API random sin proporcionar código te ayudaré, saliendo y volviendo a lo que preguntas, te puedo sugerir usar `filectime();` si quieres conservar esos datos, lógicamente necesita ser formateado con `date();`, un simple ejemplo:

```
$carpeta = "micarpeta";
$archivo = "micarpeta/archivo.zip";

echo "Fecha/hora de creación de la carpeta: " . date("d F Y  h:i:s A", filectime($carpeta));

echo "Fecha/hora de creación de la archivo: " . date("d F Y  h:i:s A", filectime($archivo));
```

Lógicamente si modificas el archivo se torna la fecha de modificación, dudo que sea posible en esa parte,

ahora puedes modificar el tiempo de modificación del archivo con `touch();`
lógicamente después de haber copiado los archivos, ejemplo:

```
$carpeta = "micarpeta";
$archivo = "micarpeta/archivo.zip";

$bktimea = filectime($archivo); // obtener tiempo unix
$bktimeb = filectime($carpeta); // no he probado con carpetas pero debería funcionar

// copiar elemento
// ...

touch($archivo, $bktimea); // establecemos la fecha/hora original...

touch($carpeta, $bktimeb);
```

Comment: he podido usar este procedimiento para conservar las propiedades de ficheros, mediante la función filectime(). Para el caso de directorios falla, tanto filectime(), filemtime(), fstat()... No estoy en un entonrno **unix** lo que parece que afecta al uso de estas funciones.

Comment: @Orici en que sistema intentas hacer esto?

Comment: @nikomaster en windows tenes esto fuera de PHP https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-pRJTf64q2dfWLoXFReqNLg&tduid=(3b0d99fdb406a09b5054b2968a8aca62)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-pRJTf64q2dfWLoXFReqNLg)()

Comment: @Victor - Random puedes intentar ejecutar una copia manual a través de si no me equivoco `system();` o `exec();` no recuerdo bien, el cual había un comando para copiar archivos sin alterar los datos que especificas a través del cmd lógicamente, pero perderás gran parte del rendimiento del código haciendo esto.

Comment: @nikomaster estoy usando Xampp, en Windows. De cualquier forma intento que el script funcione si cambia la plataforma.